# restricted permissions for cpp file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, c++

I have c++ file which contain some line of codes I want to make sure if I run this cpp file it won't harm my system for example my c++ file contain this code

```
remove("importantfile.txt");
```

I want to some how remove permissions form this file and avoid editing or deleting my system files is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: if you're on a BSD, you might have access to `pledge()` which would allow you to drop filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The way to test this is to create a separate (unprivileged) user and run the program as that user.